# Fedora 24 nvidia driver black screen

Tags: linux, drivers, fedora, xorg, nvidia-graphics-card

kinda unexperienced i was trying to setup the nvidia drivers according to a guide. http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2015/fedora-nvidia-guide/ after the reboot the machine crashed gdm. I have been googling my problems for four hours and at this point i only get a black screen after grub. that happend after i tried reverting to nouveau just to get the machine into a working state. I can SSH into the machine and it works there. But the screen is totally black, but does not go into sleep so maybe there is some signal coming across.

Thanks for any help in advance and i don't know if i should put xorg logs or any of the sort in here so if you need more info by all means ask.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem in the following way:

1. Open `/etc/sysconfig/grub` for editing
2. Append `rd.driver.blacklist=nouveau` to the end of `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="..."`

   Example row:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rd.lvm.lv=fedora/swap rd.lvm.lv=fedora/root rhgb quiet rd.driver.blacklist=nouveau"
   ```
3. Update GRUB:

   - BIOS

     ```
     grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
     ```
   - UEFI

     ```
     grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg
     ```

Reboot and it will work fine. I'm using the NVIDIA driver for my GTX970 on Fedora.

Comment: after update to fedora 25 it is not working. I delete this from grub.